# is it possible to have dynamic tour from real time data kml

Tags: dynamic, real-time, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is there a way to make a tour that is getting the coordinates from a script and updating the tour?

I am getting the data from a python script and then want to update the fly to coordiantes in the tour in real time but dont know how to do that

I tried using a network link but it wasnt working and im not sure if i use the animatedupdate or not

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it may be possible using a NetworkLinkControl in KML. You would need a total of four KML files to achieve it. In your scenario the first three could be hard coded, and the fourth could generate from your python script.

1. **load-tour.kml** - a NetworkLink file that loads tour.kml
2. **tour.kml** - a file that holds the original KML tour data
3. **update-tour.kml** - a NetworkLink file that loads the updated tour new-data.kml
4. **new-data.kml** - a NetworkLinkControl that updates the original tour.kml

Here are the four files, I have missed out the KML declaration and root element for brevity...

**load-tour.kml**

```
<NetworkLink>
  <name>load</name>
  <Link>
    <href>tour.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

**tour.kml**

```
<Document>
  <gx:Tour id="myTour">
    <name>tour</name>
    <gx:Playlist id="myPlaylist">
    <!-- existing tour data goes here -->
    </gx:Playlist>
  </gx:Tour>
</Document>
```

**update-tour.kml**

```
<NetworkLink>
  <name>update</name>
  <Link>
    <href>new-data.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

**new-data.kml**

```
<NetworkLinkControl>
  <Update>
    <targetHref>tour.kml</targetHref>
    <Change>
      <gx:Playlist id="myPlaylist">
        <!-- new tour data goes here -->
      </gx:Playlist>
    </Change>
  </Update>
</NetworkLinkControl>
```

Here is the documentation on the networklinkcontrol and its use in updating data.

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklinkcontrol

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates

Answer (score 0):

You can have a NetworkLink update the camera position automatically by using **flytoView**.  It's not an actual Tour but works similarly.  Each time it loads the link, it flies to a new LookAt or Camera element in the linked KML.

**root.kml**

```
<NetworkLink>
  <Link><href>new_camera.kml</href></Link>
  ...
  <flyToView>1</flyToView>
</NetworkLink>
```

**new_camera.kml**

```
<Document>
  <Camera>...
  or
  <LookAt>...
</Document>
```

I haven't had success updating a playing Tour from NetworkLink, other than changing the Tour name element.  I tried starting a looping Tour and then changing the Playlist or FlyTo elements from NetworkLinkControl, but I only see the camera change if I manually restart the Tour.